# what is -vu in curl command

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, postman

> curl -X POST -vu clientapp:123456 http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H
>   "Accept: application/json" -d
>   "password=spring&username=roy&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=123456&client_id=clientapp"

we wanted to execute the above cURL command in PostMan. But we don't where to put the clientapp:123456.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's bit late, I would like to answer the question which is as below :
You need to set the **-vu** values as **username** and **password** trough basic auth.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Short options can usually be combined, so `-vu` is the same as `-v -u`.

`man curl` says:

```
-v, --verbose
              Be  more  verbose/talkative during the operation. Useful for debugging and seeing what's going on "under the hood". A line starting with '>'
              means "header data" sent by curl, '<' means "header data" received by curl that is hidden in normal cases, and  a  line  starting  with  '*'
              means additional info provided by curl.
-u, --user <user:password>
              Specify the user name and password to use for server authentication. Overrides -n, --netrc and --netrc-optional.
```

Comment: Thanks! but what is clientapp:123456 in the above? @renemilk

Comment: `clientapp` is the username and `123456` is the password, specified in the format that curl wants: seperated by `:`

Comment: This is actually visible in the manpage, and it's in the source view of the blockqoute in my answer, but it's not rendered...